# how to shuffle image on recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, shuffle

i want to suffle my grid recylerview on button click. how do i do that

here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
Context mContext;
Button suffle;
List<ImageData> data = new ArrayList<>();
 Recycle_Adapter adapter = new Recycle_Adapter(mContext, data);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    suffle = (Button)findViewById(R.id.suffle);

    for(int i =0;i<Glob.imgs.length;i++) {
        data.add(new ImageData(Glob.imgs[i]));
    }

    try {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleGridView);
        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
         recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    suffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}
```

i used Collections.Shuffle(data); but its not working,maybe i dont know how to used, i just found and try to use, i have no clue, help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Collections.shuffle(list)` to shuffle your list and supply that shuffled list back to the adapter as shown below

```
suffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Collections.shuffle(data);

        adapter = new Recycle_Adapter(mContext, data);
        recyclerView.swapAdapter(data, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: its working.. thank you..  and now i want to apply shuffle animation. how do i do that.

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick for your button do the shuffle. 
Then call adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged() like this:

```
suffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Create this method in your adapter class and inside it call
        // shuffle on the list of items
        adapter.shuffleList(); 
        // Then notify the adapter that changes have been made to the list
        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount());
    }
});
```